# Where is libsystemd.so located on ARM devices?

Tags: debian, libraries, directory-structure, shared-library

I have an ARM Tinkerboard running Debian 9.8 (Stretch). Systemd version is 232. I'm working on a program that can be run from userland or as a daemon. If it is run as a daemon, then `dlopen` and `dlsym` are used to locate Systemd [`sd_notify(3)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_notify.html) entry points.

According to the [`sd_notify(3)` man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_notify.html):

> These APIs are implemented as a shared library, which can be compiled and linked to with the libsystemd pkg-config(1) file.

Unfortunately, I cannot find `libsystemd.so`. This is a userland test to simulate a service load:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=/lib/libsystemd.so NOTIFY_SOCKET=-1 ./myprog.exe
ERROR: ld.so: object '/lib/libsystemd.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
```

It does not seem to be located in the standard locations:

```
$ find /lib -name libsystemd.so
$ find /usr -name libsystemd.so
$
```

In fact:

```
$ sudo find / -name libsystemd.so
$
```

Where is the shared library located?

Answer (score 3):

`libsystemd.so` is a symbolic link provided by the `libsystemd-dev` package, which is only useful to build programs that use the library. Its target is `libsystemd.so.0` which is provided by the `libsystemd0` package, which provides what is needed to run programs that use the library. If you could find `libsystemd.so` on your PC but not on your Arm device, it's because you've installed a development environment environment on your PC but not in the Arm device.

This is the case for most libraries. The library file that programs use contains a version number: `libfoo.so.VERSION`. This allows the system to have multiple incompatible versions of the library: each version is identified by a number and is its own file. The Debian package name also includes the library version number: `libfooVERSION`. If you have the development files for the library (headers and the static library `libfoo.a`), they come with a symbolic link `libfoo.so` pointing to the version of the library that the programs you build will use.

So run `find /lib /usr/lib -name libsystemd.so.0`.
Or run `ldd` against any executable that is dynamically linked against the library (as opposed to loading it at runtime with `dlopen`), e.g. `ldd /usr/bin/dbus-daemon`.
Or search installed packages with `dpkg -S libsystemd.so.0`.
Or search available packages with `apt-file search libsystemd.so.0` (assuming `apt-file` is set up).
Or [look it up online](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_contents).

```
LD_PRELOAD=/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libsystemd.so.0 …
```

Comment: Thanks Giles. I did not realize it did not use the name `libsystemd.so`. I thought that symlink always existed. I did not need to install it once I used the correct name. Preloading `/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libsystemd.so.0` caused an error.  I needed `LD_PRELOAD=/lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-232.so`. If interested: [libsystemd.so locations on Tinkerboard](https://pastebin.com/VmV4sK08)